# AngularJS controllers mixed up each other

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am building a Single Page Application via AngularJS all of my controllers working just fine one by one but when I put them side by side inside tabs the problem is starting.

Firstly here my tabs

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="plan" ng-include="'plan.html'" ng-controller="dailyController" class="tab-pane fade in active"></div>
  <div id="program" ng-include="'program.html'" ng-controller="programController" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
  <div id="secreter" ng-include="'secreter.html'" ng-controller="secreterController" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
  <div id="responsibility" ng-include="'responsibility_lists.html'" ng-controller="responsiblityCtrl" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
  <div id="appointment" ng-include="'appointment.html'" ng-controller="appointmentCtrl" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
  <div id="dayoff" ng-include="'dayoff.html'" ng-controller="dayOffCtrl" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
  <div id="message" ng-include="'message.html'" ng-controller="messageCtrl" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
  <div id="pre_record_admin" ng-include src="'pre_record_admin.html'" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
  <div id="settings" ng-include="'settings.html'" ng-controller="settingsController" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
</div>
```

My problem is between 'program' and 'secreter' tabs their controllers has a lot of same named functions and variables.

This two pages includes two date inputs and generating a table according to this date input's value but when I changed the date input from program.html page it triggers the table in secreter.html page and vice versa I couldn't figure out why.

This is the input of program.html

```
<input class="form-control pull-left" style="width:90%" type="date" ng-model="selectedDate" ng-change="dateChangeProgram(selectedDate);">
```

And this is the input of secreter.html

```
<input class="form-control pull-left" style="width:85%" type="date" ng-model="selectedDate" ng-change="dateChange(selectedDate);">
```

I changed programController's declaration as program

```
ng-controller="programController as program"
```

and changed declarion of variables and functions with 'this' instead of '$scope' and of course my html too

```
<input class="form-control pull-left" style="width:90%" type="date" ng-model="program.selectedDate" ng-change="program.dateChangeProgram(program.selectedDate);"></input>
```

But that didn't help.

programController declaration

```
.controller('programController', function($scope,$q,$window,$log,$http,$filter,$parse,$document) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.days=[];
  vm.students=[];
//Functions and variables...
```

secreterController declaration

```
.controller('secreterController', function($scope,$q,$window,$log,$http,$filter,$parse,$document) {
    $scope.days=[];
    $scope.students=[];
//Functions and variables...
```

Comment: Is the outer div(`<div class="tab-content">`) managed by any other controller?

Comment: don't use `ng-controller`, use a component that references its own controller

Comment: @lealceldeiro none of parent elements or html page doesn't manage by any controllers

Comment: @Daniel_L you mean should I define controller inside my target html page ?

Comment: @SuatKarabacak http://busypeoples.github.io/post/thinking-in-components-angular-js/

Comment: Could you post the relevant part of your `programController` when implemented the `ng-controller="programController as program"` alternative?

Comment: @lealceldeiro I added controllers part to the question

Comment: Would be glad to help, but there isn't enough info here to determine the cause of your problem. Post a plunker, with a stripped down example of the problem occurring (don't need charts and such, just a base data element that is changing when you don't want it to). I have set one up that has nav, multiple controllers with one for each tab, days and a function that changes a value. **[Check it out here](http://plnkr.co/edit/b3mOJ5?p=preview)**.

Comment: @RobM I will edit according to my problem as soon as I can

Comment: @RobM I belive I solved the problem and it occurs because of two tables in different html pages including same-id <td> elements I changed that and problem is gone for now. I will disable the question for prevent misunderstanding.